# How to divide rows of data into separate groups based on the value of a column in the data set and calculate the total time of each group?

Tags: r, subset, addition, cumulative-sum, tibble

I have telemetry data that lists the detections of an individual whenever they have been in this zone.

For each session, I want to calculate the total time the individual was in that zone. I assume that the individual was in that zone when a detection occurred.

I want to split the rows of data into separate sessions depending on whether the "id56wtimelag" column has a value greater than 86,400.

Then, I want to be able to calculate the number of sessions and the duration of each session in which the person was here. The left column contains only the list of detections. The columns Channel..T, ag.ID, Antenna and Power can be ignored.

```
      Channel..T ag.ID Antenna Power                dat2 id56wtimelag
9              7    56      A0   206 2022-12-17 16:03:18      NA secs
11             7    56      A0   184 2022-12-17 16:03:31      13 secs
12             7    56      A0   182 2022-12-17 16:03:35       4 secs
13             7    56      A0   180 2022-12-17 16:03:39       4 secs
15             7    56      A0   206 2022-12-17 16:03:55      16 secs
16             7    56      A0   206 2022-12-17 16:03:59       4 secs
19             7    56      A0   169 2022-12-17 16:05:37      98 secs
20             7    56      A0   173 2022-12-17 16:05:41       4 secs
21             7    56      A0   187 2022-12-17 16:05:45       4 secs
17729          7    56      A0   100 2023-01-04 12:42:53 1543028 secs
17730          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:42:57       4 secs
17731          7    56      A0   118 2023-01-04 12:43:01       4 secs
17732          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:43:13      12 secs
17733          7    56      A0   102 2023-01-04 12:43:17       4 secs
17734          7    56      A0    96 2023-01-04 12:43:21       4 secs
17738          7    56      A0   106 2023-01-04 12:43:36      15 secs
17739          7    56      A0   108 2023-01-04 12:43:40       4 secs
17742          7    56      A0   111 2023-01-04 12:43:57      17 secs
17743          7    56      A0    95 2023-01-04 12:44:01       4 secs
17744          7    56      A0   101 2023-01-04 12:44:05       4 secs
17748          7    56      A0   106 2023-01-04 12:44:17      12 secs
17749          7    56      A0   105 2023-01-04 12:44:21       4 secs
17750          7    56      A0   105 2023-01-04 12:44:25       4 secs
17753          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:44:37      12 secs
17754          7    56      A0   100 2023-01-04 12:44:41       4 secs
17755          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:44:45       4 secs
17759          7    56      A0    96 2023-01-04 12:44:58      13 secs
17760          7    56      A0    93 2023-01-04 12:45:08      10 secs
17763          7    56      A0    95 2023-01-04 12:45:28      20 secs
17765          7    56      A0    86 2023-01-04 12:45:48      20 secs
17767          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:46:08      20 secs
17769          7    56      A0    85 2023-01-04 12:46:28      20 secs
17772          7    56      A0    89 2023-01-04 12:46:48      20 secs
17774          7    56      A0   102 2023-01-04 12:47:08      20 secs
17776          7    56      A0   109 2023-01-04 12:47:28      20 secs
17777          7    56      A0   103 2023-01-04 12:47:48      20 secs
17778          7    56      A0   102 2023-01-04 12:48:08      20 secs
17779          7    56      A0   100 2023-01-04 12:48:28      20 secs
17780          7    56      A0   107 2023-01-04 12:48:38      10 secs
17781          7    56      A0   102 2023-01-04 12:48:58      20 secs
17782          7    56      A0   100 2023-01-04 12:49:18      20 secs
17783          7    56      A0    94 2023-01-04 12:49:38      20 secs
```

I'm having trouble splitting the rows into separate groups/sessions based on the criteria when the "id56wtimelag" column has a value greater than 86,400. Then I would need to calculate the duration of each session, ideally contained in a list like this for this dataset:

```
`Session  Length of each session (seconds)
1  147
2  405`
```

---

## Data

Data set in `dput` format.

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    Channel..T = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                   7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                   7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                   7L, 7L), 
    ag.ID = c(56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
              56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
              56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
              56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L), 
    Antenna = c("A0", "A0", "A0", 
                "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
                "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
                "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", 
                "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0", "A0"), 
    Power = c(206L, 184L, 182L, 
              180L, 206L, 206L, 169L, 173L, 187L, 100L, 103L, 118L, 103L, 102L, 
              96L, 106L, 108L, 111L, 95L, 101L, 106L, 105L, 105L, 103L, 100L, 
              103L, 96L, 93L, 95L, 86L, 103L, 85L, 89L, 102L, 109L, 103L, 102L, 
              100L, 107L, 102L, 100L, 94L), 
    dat2 = c("2022-12-17 16:03:18", 
             "2022-12-17 16:03:31", "2022-12-17 16:03:35", "2022-12-17 16:03:39", 
             "2022-12-17 16:03:55", "2022-12-17 16:03:59", "2022-12-17 16:05:37", 
             "2022-12-17 16:05:41", "2022-12-17 16:05:45", "2023-01-04 12:42:53", 
             "2023-01-04 12:42:57", "2023-01-04 12:43:01", "2023-01-04 12:43:13", 
             "2023-01-04 12:43:17", "2023-01-04 12:43:21", "2023-01-04 12:43:36", 
             "2023-01-04 12:43:40", "2023-01-04 12:43:57", "2023-01-04 12:44:01", 
             "2023-01-04 12:44:05", "2023-01-04 12:44:17", "2023-01-04 12:44:21", 
             "2023-01-04 12:44:25", "2023-01-04 12:44:37", "2023-01-04 12:44:41", 
             "2023-01-04 12:44:45", "2023-01-04 12:44:58", "2023-01-04 12:45:08", 
             "2023-01-04 12:45:28", "2023-01-04 12:45:48", "2023-01-04 12:46:08", 
             "2023-01-04 12:46:28", "2023-01-04 12:46:48", "2023-01-04 12:47:08", 
             "2023-01-04 12:47:28", "2023-01-04 12:47:48", "2023-01-04 12:48:08", 
             "2023-01-04 12:48:28", "2023-01-04 12:48:38", "2023-01-04 12:48:58", 
             "2023-01-04 12:49:18", "2023-01-04 12:49:38"), 
    id56wtimelag = c("NA secs", 
                     "13 secs", "4 secs", "4 secs", "16 secs", "4 secs", "98 secs", 
                     "4 secs", "4 secs", "1543028 secs", "4 secs", "4 secs", "12 secs", 
                     "4 secs", "4 secs", "15 secs", "4 secs", "17 secs", "4 secs", 
                     "4 secs", "12 secs", "4 secs", "4 secs", "12 secs", "4 secs", 
                     "4 secs", "13 secs", "10 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", 
                     "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", 
                     "20 secs", "10 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs", "20 secs")), 
    row.names = c("9", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "19", "20", "21", 
                  "17729", "17730", "17731", "17732", "17733", "17734", "17738", "17739", 
                  "17742", "17743", "17744", "17748", "17749", "17750", "17753", "17754", 
                  "17755", "17759", "17760", "17763", "17765", "17767", "17769", 
                  "17772", "17774", "17776", "17777", "17778", "17779", "17780", 
                  "17781", "17782", "17783"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal reproducible example. If "Channel..T, ag.ID, Antenna, and Power columns can be ignored.", then you should remove those from the example data.
Please always provide the data as code, rather than formated data. This will allow us to paste it into our own consoles. You can paste the output of `dput(data)`

Comment: Please provide data using `dput()`, i.e. `dput(your_data[c("dat2", "id56wtimelag")])` if those are the relevant columns. I think you want to create a grouping variable, i.e. `ifelse(your_data$id56wtimelag > 864000, TRUE, FALSE)`. What have you tried so far? Please have in mind that SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

1. Remove the string `secs` the duration column `id56wtimelag` and coerce it to integer;
2. Get a logical vector of where `id56wtimelag` is greater than or equal to 86,400;
3. Create `Length`, a copy of that column, we will need it because it contains `NA`'s and by working on a copy, the original remains intact;
4. assign zero wherever `Length` is >= 86,400;
5. and `FALSE` to all `NA`'s in `Session`;
6. Now the sessions numbers. A standard `cumsum` trick will make a vector increasing every time `Session` is `TRUE`.

Then the sessions' durations are computed with `aggregate`.

```r
df1$id56wtimelag <- gsub("[[:alpha:]]*|[[:space:]]*", "", df1$id56wtimelag) |>
  as.integer()

Session <- df1$id56wtimelag >= 86400L
Length <- df1$id56wtimelag
Length[Session] <- 0L
Session[is.na(Session)] <- FALSE
Session <- cumsum(Session) + 1L
aggregate(Length ~ Session, FUN = sum)
#>   Session Length
#> 1       1    147
#> 2       2    405
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-11 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>